# What to do about "WARN Ignoring unexpected exception"

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, apache-tika

I'm using Apache Tika to search files for given text. My method `contains` (below) looks like it should return `true` if `file` contains `s` and no exception arises; otherwise, `false`.

```
  public static boolean contains(File file, String s) throws MalformedURLException, 
                     IOException, MimeTypeException, SAXException, TikaException
  {
    InputStream         stream    = new FileInputStream(file);
    AutoDetectParser    parser    = new AutoDetectParser();
    BodyContentHandler  handler   = new BodyContentHandler(-1);
    Metadata            metadata  = new Metadata();
    try
    {
      parser.parse(stream, handler, metadata);
      return handler.toString().toLowerCase().contains(s.toLowerCase());
    }
    catch (IOException | SAXException | TikaException e)
    {
      txaErrorsAppend(file + ": " + e + "\n");
      return false;
    }
  }
```

(The code--notably the `throws` clause and declarations--came from a Tika example.)

But the `try`-`catch` didn't catch the "`unexpected exception`" below, which occurred on the `parser` line in the code:

```
WARN  Ignoring unexpected exception while parsing summary entry SummaryInformation
java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: Codepage number may not be 0
    at org.apache.poi.util.CodePageUtil.codepageToEncoding(CodePageUtil.java:277)
    at org.apache.poi.util.CodePageUtil.codepageToEncoding(CodePageUtil.java:255)
    at org.apache.poi.util.CodePageUtil.getStringFromCodePage(CodePageUtil.java:233)
    at org.apache.poi.util.CodePageUtil.getStringFromCodePage(CodePageUtil.java:221)
    at org.apache.poi.hpsf.CodePageString.getJavaValue(CodePageString.java:69)
    at org.apache.poi.hpsf.VariantSupport.read(VariantSupport.java:210)
    at org.apache.poi.hpsf.Property.<init>(Property.java:165)
    at org.apache.poi.hpsf.Section.<init>(Section.java:277)
    at org.apache.poi.hpsf.PropertySet.init(PropertySet.java:451)
    at org.apache.poi.hpsf.PropertySet.<init>(PropertySet.java:246)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.SummaryExtractor.parseSummaryEntryIfExists(SummaryExtractor.java:81)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.SummaryExtractor.parseSummaries(SummaryExtractor.java:71)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.OfficeParser.parse(OfficeParser.java:126)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.OfficeParser.parse(OfficeParser.java:117)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:280)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:280)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser.parse(AutoDetectParser.java:120)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser.parse(AutoDetectParser.java:136)
    at search2.TASK.contains(TASK.java:410)
    at search2.TASK$FV.visitFile(TASK.java:213)
    at search2.TASK$FV.visitFile(TASK.java:104)
    at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2670)
    at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2742)
    at search2.TASK.doInBackground(TASK.java:434)
    at search2.TASK.doInBackground(TASK.java:41)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(SwingWorker.java:295)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(SwingWorker.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I originally had `catch (Exception e);` but Netbeans 8.0.2 had suggested the `catch` shown in the code above.

Should I have have stayed with `catch (Exception e)`?

Should I add to the `catch` the other exception types listed in the `throws` clause?

Are there some exceptions that `try`-`catch` can't catch?

Note that the program didn't terminate. Since the message started "`WARN   Ignoring unexpected exception`", should I just forget it happened and go about whatever's next?

Comment: Your `catch` block seems fine. It's a bad practise to `catch Exception`, because you should only catch exception types you can handle. In your specific case, the `catch` block is never reached because the exception is caught earlier in the call stack; more specifically by [`SummaryExtractor.parseSummaryEntryIfExists()`](http://fossies.org/linux/tika/tika-parsers/src/main/java/org/apache/tika/parser/microsoft/SummaryExtractor.java), where (ironically) there's this block of code: `catch (Exception e) {logger.warn("Ignoring unexpected exception while parsing summary entry " + entryName, e); }`.

Comment: The actual problem (`java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: Codepage number may not be 0`) is likely related to the file you're parsing. Do you get the same problem with all files?

Comment: @MickMnemonic--first time I've gotten the warning. There have been plenty of non-exception warnings, such as encrypted file. But almost all files are read with no problem.`